# Не подгружается javascript во вложенном PHP (DateRangePicker && Livesearch)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, include

Добрый день!

Есть не совсем адекватная система со вложенными друг в друга php файлами.

т.е. в index.php вложен `include`-ом `somefile.php`, который состоит из других вложенных друг в друга файлов `.php`

в одном из них, примерно на пятом уровне вложения, среди прочей верстки в контейнере `<script></script>` лежат `DateRangePicker` и `ajax`-овая приблуда для живого поиска подсказок в БД.

`DateRangePicker` крепиться к `<input />` по `id`. Там все просто и все должно работать, но увы и ах не инициализируется.

`ajax` даже отправляет запросы, что видно в консоле, но ответа не получает.

При этом, если файл `.php` в котором все это содержится не прикреплять через `include`, а просто вставить код из него в файл уровнем выше - все замечательно работает.

все инклуды `somefile.php` находятся в той же папке, что и родительский файл.

Чем может быть вызвана такая проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Явно проблема вызвана не тем, что файлы вложены, сервер возвращает браузеру html и там неважно что во что вложено. Откройте вкладку network в отладчике хрома при загрузке странице (откройте заранее и загрузите страницу) и посмотрите подробности ajax запроса: какие данные уходят на сервер, какой статус приходит, какой ответ от сервера.

Comment: Подключается после. Ну т.е. она не висит в `document.ready` отдельным скриптом. После ввода в инпут (инициируется на `onkeyup`) данные уходят верные, статус 200 ОК. Но в результате ответная информация - не грузится.

Comment: Надо смотреть контроллер на который уходит запрос, почему он ничего не возвращает. Также стоит посмотреть уходит ли введенная строка с запросом на сервер. Сделайте возврат-заглушку в контроллере к которому обращается ajax.